# Understanding interface with animal classes

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, interface, polymorphism

I made this small program to demonstrate to myself an example of interface.  I wanted to confirm whether it is correct and if there is anything more I should know about interfaces other than the importance of implementing polymorphism and multiple inheritance.

```
//program.cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dog oDog = new Dog();
        Console.WriteLine(oDog.Cry());

        Cat oCat = new Cat();
        Console.WriteLine(oCat.Cry());

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

//IAnimal.cs
interface IAnimal
{
    string Cry();
}


//Dog.cs
class Dog : IAnimal
{
    public string Cry()
    {
        return "Woof!";
    }
}


//Cat.cs
class Cat : IAnimal
{
    public string Cry()
    {
        return "Meow!";
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to know more about interfaces, Code Review is not the right site.

Comment: Why is that? I am just asking my example to be reviewed.

Comment: But you asked for more than that. “are there anything more I should know about interfaces” That doesn't have anything to do with reviewing your code.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your example accesses the cat through a variable of type `Cat` and the dog through `Dog`. This would work, even if both classes did not implement a common interface. Inheritance is not involved.

In order to really demonstrate the usefulness of polymorphism I suggest the following code:

```
interface IAnimal
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    string Cry();
}

class Dog : IAnimal
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Cry()
    {
        return "Woof!";
    }
}

class Cat : IAnimal
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Cry()
    {
        return "Meow!";
    }
}
```

And here is a possible test:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var animals = new List<IAnimal>();

    animals.Add(new Dog { Name = "Robby" });
    animals.Add(new Dog { Name = "Fify" });
    animals.Add(new Cat { Name = "Mimy" });

    PrintAnimals(animals);

    Console.ReadKey();
}

private static void PrintAnimals(IEnumerable<IAnimal> animals)
{
    foreach (IAnimal animal in animals) {
        Console.WriteLine("Here is {0}: {1}", animal.Name, animal.Cry());
    }
}
```

It demonstrates that different types of animals can be treated the same way, but behave differently. This is what polymorphism is about. The word means many (poly) shapes or forms (morph). You can add different types of animals to a collection.

The `PrintAnimals` method has a parameter of type `IEnumerable<IAnimal>` allowing you to pass it different types of collections (arrays, lists, linked lists, stacks and many more, as yet another example of polymorphism). It uses a unique `Console.WriteLine` statement for all types of animals, without even knowing of which type an animal really is. The only thing it knows is, that it implements `IAnimal`. You could even add new types of animals later, without having to change the `PrintAnimals` method and it would still work as expected.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit how this demonstrates more of interface?

Comment: Your example accesses the cat through a variable of type `Cat` and the dog through `Dog`. This would work, even if both classes did not implement the interface. Inheritance is not involved. My `PrintAnimals` method does not need to know the `Cat` and `Dog` classes. `PrintAnimals` could be defined in a different assembly where `Cat` and `Dog` are not accessible (if they are not `public`). Both, cats and dogs, are accessed through the same variable `IAnimal animal`. You could even add a new kind of animal later. `PrintAnimals` would still work without any changes and without recompilation.

Comment: "Polymorphism is the ability of derived classes inheriting from the same base class to respond to the same method call in their own unique way" -Beginning C# OOP By Dan Clark. So, in my example, I inherited from IAnimal and had different implementation of Cry depending on the class (Dog,Cat). So, is not that all? Why is it important to have a PrintAnimal method to demonstrate Polymorphism?

Comment: Your example does not respond to the same method call. It responds to `Dog.Cry` and `Cat.Cry`. Those are are two different methods. My example always reponds to the same method call `IAnimal.Cry`. You wrote `Dog oDog = new Dog();`. If you changed it to `IAnimal oDog = new Dog();`, you would be responding to the same method call.

Answer (score 4):

Your code is quite simple and works, there is not much to review.

Few points:

1. You shouldn't use variable names like `oDog`. If the `o` is meant to indicate that it's an object, then that information already contained in the type of the variable, so the prefix is useless. If it indicates something else, then it's very confusing.
2. Your code is not a very good example, because it would work exactly the same even without the interface.

Comment: Yes, about anything is an object in C#, and thousands of types are available in the class library, making it virtually impossible to find an appropriate prefix for one of them.

Comment: How would it work exactly the same without interface?
Without interface an Animal class would have the Cry() method and it would not vary according to the class it was inherited by e.g.Dog and Cat.

Comment: @Md.lbrahim There is no `Animal` class in the code you posted. And the `Main()` method really doesn't use the interface in any way.

Answer (score 2):

An interface is like a contract. In you case - all clases that inherits from `IAnimal` must have a `Cry()` method... (which is really mean :) )

In in you example you are not really using the interface.  try writing it like this:

```
IAnimal animal1 = new Dog();
Console.WriteLine(animal1.Cry());

IAnimal animal2 = new Cat();
Console.WriteLine(animal2.Cry());
```

And see that it still works.

Now try adding a method to your `Cat` class. Perhaps an `Eat()` method.

```
class Cat : IAnimal {
    public string Cry()
    {
        return "Meow!";
    }

    public string Eat()
    {
      return "Meow i'm so full - mice is my favorite!";
    } }
```

And then try calling that method with `animal2` instance. You will notes you can't!

`animal2.Eat(); //<-- compile time error`

Because we are now using `animal2` only as `IAnimal`. And all we know about an `IAnimal` is that it can `Cry()`

Answer (score 1):

A better exercise/code snippet to demonstrate the usefulness of an interface would be something like:

```
static void PrintAnimal(IAnimal animal)
{
    Console.WriteLine(animal.Cry());
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IAnimal dog = new Dog();
    IAnimal cat = new Cat();
    PrintAnimal(dog);
    PrintAnimal(cat);

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

The client expecting the interface (`IAnimal`) only cares about that interface and not the specific implementation (`Dog`, `Cat`, etc). Therefore you could have the `PrintAnimal` method (maybe class at some point) handle any kind of animal you may happen to want in the future.  Your example would work whether you had an interface or not.